# WSS4J Invalid Digital Signature

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature, xml-signature, wss4j

We are generating an XML SOAP message but the receiving gateway (EMIS) responds with a message to say the the signature is invalid:

INVALID_REQUEST
Invalid digital signature

If we run verification against the soap payload, as so:

```
        DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(new X509KeySelector(publicKey), signatureNode);
   Element elTS = (Element) ts;
            valContext.setIdAttributeNS(elTS, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "Id");
 XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
 signatureIsValid = signature.validate(valContext);
            if (signatureIsValid == false) {
boolean sv = signature.getSignatureValue().validate(valContext);
 if (sv == false) {
  Iterator i = signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences().iterator();
for (int j=0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
    Reference ref = ((Reference) i.next());
  boolean refValid = ref.validate(valContext);
}
}
```

Then the message is:

```
URI:#Timestamp-1
**** #Timestamp-1 validity status: true
Verification returned:false
```

The signature pathway is:

```
      SOAPConstants soapConstants = WSSecurityUtil.getSOAPConstants(doc.getDocumentElement());
          WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader(doc);
          secHeader.insertSecurityHeader();

          WSSecSignature builder = new WSSecSignature(secHeader);
          builder.setUserInfo( KEY_ALIAS, KEY_ENTRY_PASS);



          builder.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);
          builder.setAddInclusivePrefixes(true);

          WSEncryptionPart tsEP =new WSEncryptionPart(ts.getId());
          builder.getParts().add(tsEP);

           LOGGER.info("Signing doc");


         Document signedDoc = builder.build(crypto);
```

Any ideas ?